# Как найти значение id с помощью регулярки?

Tags: python, re

Текст

```
0588235294},{"cianUserId":33070713,"name":"Анна Козинцева","age":"3 года и 1 мес. на Циан","avatarUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fwww.cian.ru\u002Favatar.axd?i=13558095&t=2&p=2"
```

Нужно с помощью re в python найти значение ключа cianUserId.
А если это json, то тогда как можно его от туда взять. Потому что сам форматер говорит, что это не подходит как json.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем использовать регулярное выражение, если это json, который можно распарсить как json и достать данные?

Comment: Это js я просто не полностью скинул

Comment: Суть вопроса не поменялась. Есть json, из которого можно достать cianUserId, зачем регулярное выражение?

Comment: Это не json а список в javasript. А спарсил это просто на странице. Вот фрагмент window._cianConfig = window._cianConfig || {};
window._cianConfig['agents-directory-frontend'] = (window._cianConfig['agents-directory-frontend'] || []).concat([{"key":"projectName","value":"agents-directory-frontend","priority":1000,"filter":{}},{"key":"mcsRunEnv","value":"PROD","priority":1000,"filter":{}},{"key":"mcsRunEnvType","value":"prod","priority":1000,"filter":{}},{"key":"version","value":"[agents-directory-frontend][CD-147151][44240da5]","priority":1000,"filter":{"request-id":"fab7343d4e55"}},

Comment: Это JSON, а не JS. JSON - это формат данных, а JS - язык программирования

Comment: Тем не менее проблема в чем? В python можно распарсить JSON json.loads(json) и после вытащить значение cianUserId

Comment: Ну хочет человек искать регуляркой, пусть ищет `regex = r"\"cianUserId\":(\d+)"` айди будет в 0-м совпадении в 1-й группе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у тебя всё это строкой, то вначале обрежь её, найдя начало как уникальный кусок строки, к примеру `.concat([` и аналогично найти конец, вычислить длинну и обрезать тем самым строку. Через срезы или как тебе удобно. И получив чистый JSON парсить его как тебе нужно.
А регулярки тут не нужны